# Can someone explain why I still have live objects after releasing the pointers to them?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, singleton, directx, destructor

I am experimenting with the singleton pattern to make it easier to use some common interfaces of the DirectX API, but I have a problem I can't seem to solve.

This is my definition:

```
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <DxErr.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "DxErr.lib")

class Core
{
public:
    ~Core();

    static ID3D11Device*& getDevice();
    static ID3D11DeviceContext*& getContext();
    static IDXGISwapChain*& getSwapChain();
    static ID3D11RenderTargetView*& getRenderTargetView();
    static ID3D11Debug*& getDebug();

    static HRESULT Initialize(HWND hwnd);
    static void Reset();

private:
    Core();

    HRESULT CreateDevice();

    static Core*            instance;

    ID3D11Device*           device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext*    context;

    IDXGISwapChain*         swapChain;
    IDXGIDevice1*           ddevice;
    IDXGIAdapter1*          adapter;
    IDXGIFactory1*          factory;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* rtv;
    ID3D11Debug*            debug;

    Core(Core const&);             
    void operator=(Core const&);
};
```

This is the implementation:

```
#include "Core.h"

Core* Core::instance;

Core::Core()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CreateDevice();
    if(FAILED(hr)) throw hr;
}

Core::~Core()
{
    if (device) device->Release();
    if (context) context->Release();

    if (swapChain) swapChain->Release();
    if (ddevice) ddevice->Release();
    if (adapter) adapter->Release();
    if (factory) factory->Release();
    if (rtv) rtv->Release();

    debug->ReportLiveDeviceObjects(D3D11_RLDO_DETAIL);

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get Functions
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ID3D11Device*& Core::getDevice()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        try
        {
            instance = new Core();
        }
        catch (HRESULT hr)
        {
            throw hr;
        }
    }
    return instance->device;
}

ID3D11DeviceContext*& Core::getContext()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        try
        {
            instance = new Core();
        }
        catch (HRESULT hr)
        {
            throw hr;
        }
    }
    return instance->context;
}


IDXGISwapChain*& Core::getSwapChain()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        try
        {
            instance = new Core();
        }
        catch (HRESULT hr)
        {
            throw hr;
        }
    }

    return instance->swapChain;
}

ID3D11RenderTargetView*& Core::getRenderTargetView()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        try
        {
            instance = new Core();
        }
        catch (HRESULT hr)
        {
            throw hr;
        }
    }
    return instance->rtv;
}

ID3D11Debug*& Core::getDebug()
{
    if (!instance)
    {
        try
        {
            instance = new Core();
        }
        catch (HRESULT hr)
        {
            throw hr;
        }
    }
    return instance->debug;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Other Functions
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

HRESULT Core::CreateDevice()
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;

    UINT flags = NULL;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    HRESULT hr;

    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        flags,
        featureLevels,
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &device,
        &featureLevel,
        &context);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Debug), (void**) &debug);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice1), (void**) &ddevice);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = ddevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter1), (void**) &adapter);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = adapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**) &factory);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT Core::Initialize(HWND hwnd)
{
    // Create the swap chain
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = hwnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    if (!instance)
    {
        try
        {
            instance = new Core();
        }
        catch (HRESULT hr)
        {
            return hr;
        }
    }

    instance->factory->CreateSwapChain(instance->device, &sd, &instance->swapChain);

    // Create and set the render target view
    HRESULT hr;
    ID3D11Texture2D* renderingBuffer;   
    hr = instance->swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**) &renderingBuffer);
    if(FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        renderingBuffer->Release();
        return hr;
    }
    hr = instance->device->CreateRenderTargetView(renderingBuffer, NULL, &instance->rtv);
    renderingBuffer->Release();
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    // TODO: create and set the depth stencil view

    instance->context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &instance->rtv, nullptr);

    return S_OK;
}

void Core::Reset()
{
    delete instance;
}
```

The destructor getting called, but still I see this in my output window once I exit the application:

```
D3D11 WARNING: Live ID3D11Device at 0x007A201C, Refcount: 2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #441: LIVE_DEVICE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Context at 0x007A3620, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #2097226: LIVE_CONTEXT]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3DDeviceContextState at 0x007ADBB0, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #3145742: LIVE_DEVICECONTEXTSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11BlendState at 0x007B3D84, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #435: LIVE_BLENDSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11DepthStencilState at 0x007B3ECC, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #436: LIVE_DEPTHSTENCILSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11RasterizerState at 0x007B403C, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #437: LIVE_RASTERIZERSTATE]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Sampler at 0x007B428C, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #434: LIVE_SAMPLER]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Query at 0x007B440C, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #438: LIVE_QUERY]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live IDXGISwapChain at 0x007B45B8, Refcount: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #442: LIVE_SWAPCHAIN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Texture2D at 0x007B4B1C, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #425: LIVE_TEXTURE2D]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11RenderTargetView at 0x007B4EBC, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 0 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #428: LIVE_RENDERTARGETVIEW]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live ID3D11Texture2D at 0x007B55EC, Refcount: 0, IntRef: 1 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #425: LIVE_TEXTURE2D]
```

I also checked whether the Release() functions in the destructor are actually called and they are.

I must be missing something very obvious and would greatly appreciate it if someone can point it out to me.

Also, is this my using of the singleton pattern in this case a smart thing to do?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is my DirectX class, where I use the Core class:

```
#include "DirectX.h"

DirectX::DirectX() {}
DirectX::DirectX(HWND hwnd)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = Init(hwnd);
    if(FAILED(hr)) throw hr;
    hr = Load();
    if(FAILED(hr)) throw hr;
}
DirectX::~DirectX()
{
    Core::Reset();
}

HRESULT DirectX::Init(HWND hwnd)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = Core::Initialize(hwnd);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DirectX::Load()
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DirectX::Update()
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DirectX::Render()
{
    try 
    {
        float backgroundcolor[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        Core::getContext()->ClearRenderTargetView(Core::getRenderTargetView(), backgroundcolor);
        Core::getSwapChain()->Present(0, 0);
    }
    catch (HRESULT hr)
    {
        return hr;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: You don't do anything once you have called `Reset` I hope?

Comment: I have checked. I don't. But this output get printed when I call ReportLiveDeviceObjects() right after I released them in the destructor of Core.

Comment: Two things: One is that you return a reference to all the private pointers, that means the caller may actually change the pointers. Don't return references unless that's what you want. The second thing is that you need to check what the callers are doing, maybe they do something which increases the reference counter?

Comment: I edited the post to include the class where I use the Core class.

Comment: I rewrote my code, fixed it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: So what fixed it?

Comment: @Epirocks I have just experienced this same issue, with the same output as OP and was pretty shocked no one actually told you how to fix it. If you're still wanting a solution, you need to release the `ID3D11Debug` resource as well. After a quick look OP doesn't do this in his code.

Comment: @jjmcc thanks for that. I guess the OP is not here to give solutions only to take them, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am glad you have already found the answer yourself, but may I give you some advice on the singleton pattern and Cpp?

For me it looks like you are comming from a C background switching to Cpp. I have been revieweing a lot of code for teams doing that switch and this look familar to me.

What you did there is no singleton pattern (even if it has that instance pointer). That you have a static pointer to an instance does not mean that all the methods have to be static. - What you did is a static function library operating on data in a struct that is accidently it's own instance. You could have left away the class, putting the data on a struct and you would have almost the same thing as you have. - But a singleton is something alse, it's an object operating with methods on it's own, data like you would expect from an object (like the one and only, not copyable, coffee machine in the house), not operating on static data.

Joachim Pileborg is also right about the handles to pointers, this is dangerous because anybody can assign another object per accident, leaving leaked memory and other implications what would lead to very hard to find bugs in a larger project. You should only do this with a really really good reason.

Next, you should definetely use initializer lists on the constructor for all your member variables or initialize them in the constructor another way, otherwise if somemone gets an instance and calls Reset on your class right away, the pointers are all at random adresses (not 0). Meaning the destructor will crash definitely.

As a last tip do not use pointers as your would use booleans in if statements. You write code, you are an author, try to communicate clearly what you are doing if(obj == NULL).

A basic singleton pattern is applied like this (there are other ways for more elegant instancing or thread savety, but this is the basic pattern):

**(Take care I did not compile this because I am working on a linux machine atm, there might be issues i.e. with having an & in front if this->x here and there in the CreateDevice() function, I did not check these)**

Good luck with your project!

### Core.h

```
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <DxErr.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "DxErr.lib")

class Core
{
public:
    Core* instance();
    static void Reset();

    ~Core();

    HRESULT Initialize(HWND hwnd);

    ID3D11Device* getDevice();
    ID3D11DeviceContext* getContext();
    IDXGISwapChain* getSwapChain();
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* getRenderTargetView();
    ID3D11Debug* getDebug();

private:
    static Core*            instance;

    ID3D11Device*           device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext*    context;

    IDXGISwapChain*         swapChain;
    IDXGIDevice1*           ddevice;
    IDXGIAdapter1*          adapter;
    IDXGIFactory1*          factory;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView* rtv;
    ID3D11Debug*            debug;

    HRESULT CreateDevice();

    Core();
    Core(Core const&);          
    void operator=(Core const&);
};
```

### Core.cpp

```
#include "Core.h"

Core* Core::instance;

Core* Core::instance()
{
    if (instance == NULL)
    {
        try
        {
            instance = new Core();
        }
        catch (HRESULT hr)
        {
            throw hr;
        }
    }
}

Core::Core() :
    device(NULL),
    context(NULL),
    swapChain(NULL),
    ddevice(NULL),
    adapter(NULL),
    factory(NULL),
    rtv(NULL),
    debug(NULL)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CreateDevice();
    if(FAILED(hr)) throw hr;
}

Core::~Core()
{
    if (device != NULL) device->Release();
    if (context != NULL) context->Release();

    if (swapChain != NULL) swapChain->Release();
    if (ddevice != NULL) ddevice->Release();
    if (adapter != NULL) adapter->Release();
    if (factory != NULL) factory->Release();
    if (rtv != NULL) rtv->Release();

    debug->ReportLiveDeviceObjects(D3D11_RLDO_DETAIL);
}

ID3D11Device* Core::getDevice()
{
    return this->device;
}

ID3D11DeviceContext* Core::getContext()
{
    return this->context;
}


IDXGISwapChain* Core::getSwapChain()
{
    return this->swapChain;
}

ID3D11RenderTargetView* Core::getRenderTargetView()
{
    return this->rtv;
}

ID3D11Debug* Core::getDebug()
{
    return this->debug;
}

HRESULT Core::CreateDevice()
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;

    UINT flags = NULL;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    HRESULT hr;

    hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
        NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        flags,
        featureLevels,
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &device,
        &featureLevel,
        &context);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Debug), (void**) &debug);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice1), (void**) &ddevice);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = ddevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter1), (void**) &adapter);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;
    hr = adapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory1), (void**) &factory);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT Core::Initialize(HWND hwnd)
{
    // Create the swap chain
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = hwnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    this->factory->CreateSwapChain(this->device, &sd, this->swapChain);

    // Create and set the render target view
    HRESULT hr;
    ID3D11Texture2D* renderingBuffer;   
    hr = this->swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**) &renderingBuffer);
    if(FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        renderingBuffer->Release();
        return hr;
    }
    hr = this->device->CreateRenderTargetView(renderingBuffer, NULL, this->rtv);
    renderingBuffer->Release();
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    // TODO: create and set the depth stencil view

    this->context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &this->rtv, nullptr);

    return S_OK;
}

void Core::Reset()
{
    delete instance;
}
```

### Usage

```
#include "DirectX.h"

DirectX::DirectX() {}

DirectX::DirectX(HWND hwnd)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = Init(hwnd);
    if(FAILED(hr)) throw hr;
    hr = Load();
    if(FAILED(hr)) throw hr;
}

DirectX::~DirectX()
{
    Core::instance()->Reset();
}

HRESULT DirectX::Init(HWND hwnd)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = Core::instance()->Initialize(hwnd);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DirectX::Load()
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DirectX::Update()
{
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT DirectX::Render()
{
    try 
    {
        Core* core = Core::instance();
        float backgroundcolor[4] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        core->ClearRenderTargetView(core->getRenderTargetView(), backgroundcolor);
        core->Present(0, 0);
    }
    catch (HRESULT hr)
    {
        return hr;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and effort.

Comment: while you're at it, ditch `NULL` for `nullptr` in C++.

Comment: He used NULL in the question, so I did not assume Jvlonden uses a C++11 compiler and did not want to introduce any new problems or aspects to him not related to his original problem.

Answer (score 6):

Direct3D keeps reference counts on objects even after they are Release()d by the application, as long as the object or its dependencies are bound to the 3D pipeline.

Comment: How do you unbind them then?

Comment: You can try calling the various binding functions with null/default parameters to clear out the bindings explicitly or use ID3D11DeviceContext->ClearState();  which sets everything to default or null state and then ID3D11DeviceContext->Flush(); that propogates the changes through the pipeline.